# IP address is shown instead of the Domain name

Tags: nginx, dns, ip

I just setup a AWS server and installed Nginx. I've also forwarded the public IP address to my Godaddy account. Typing the domain name on the address bar directs to the correct website but instead of seeing my domain name the public IP address is displayed.

I've followed the tutorial described here:

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/developer/204405534/install-nginx-on-ubuntu

I've done some modification in:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` referencing `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name  example.com www.example.com;
        access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;
        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html;
}
```

The expected out should be the domain name is shown rather than the ip address.

Comment: If you just installed Nginx, it's highly probable that the `sites-available` convention is deprecated. You may want to install the latest stable varsion: http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu

Comment: I've uninstalled my nginx and followed the tutorial on the provided link. When I  tried this the nginx version is 1.10.3.  After I did the same steps as described on my question. Just wondering what else I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Looks like the `PATH` still point to the old Nginx version

Comment: Thanks I've got it working. I just redeploy the a latest VM with ubunto 18 on it and install latest nginx that way. It works for me. Thanks again.